# When based your culture politeness necessitates something

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

In my culture and as I know it well in many other cultures, people especially youths are thought not to raise their voices when they are talking to someone else e.g. and elderly. I was wondering if someone could tell me whether my self-made sentence below sounds natural to indicate the mentioned message to someone who does not observe this cultural rule?

> - Politeness necessitates not to raise your voice when you’re talking to (a woman / an elderly) etc.

For me, it is grammatically correct, but I have no idea if it is structurally and constructionally correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *necessitates* seems overly formal for such an admonishment. Better to be more direct, I think:

> *Be polite! Don’t raise your voice when you’re talking to the elderly.*

(Incidentally, it’s “the elderly” when referring to the group as a whole, or “an elderly person” if you are referring to just one. You could also say “an elder” but that’s somewhat ambiguous, because, strictly speaking, a 13-year-old could be an “elder” to an 11-year old.)

If you want to stress a need somehow, you can lengthen this a little bit:

> *You need to be polite and not raise your voice when talking to an adult*.

Lastly, if you really wanted to keep your original sentence structure, you could use *dictates* instead of *necessitates*. I think that’s a better fit:

> *Politeness dictates not to raise your voice when you’re talking to a woman.*

I found this definition in [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/dictate) that describes this usage of the verb *dictate*:

> **dictate** (*v.*) to be the determining cause or motive of; fix or decide positively or unavoidably: as, *his conduct is dictated by false pride*.

For what it’s worth, an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=politeness+dictates%2Cpoliteness+necessitates&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows a modest number of hits for the phrase *politeness dictates*, but none for *politeness necessitates*.